# get name of hidden form

Tags: javascript, forms, hidden

What i want to do is get the name of the hidden form which in this case is named:6ca3787zz7n149b2d286qs777dd8357b, the problem is, that form name always changes, the only thing that is the same is its value, which is 1, well 99% of the time, the only thing that is 100% the same that i guess could be somehow used to retrieve the form name is:L2ZvcnVtcy8 which is just above it. I am also attempting to do this via running javascript manually on the browser (chrome), so having that in mind where the javascript code is run through the url bar like this javascript:codegoeshere, how can i get the form name, -->(6ca3787zz7n149b2d286qs777dd8357b)?

```
<form action="index.php?feature=xxxxxx" method="post" name="login">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Logout" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="option" value="username" />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="task" value="logout" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="L2ZvcnVtcy8=" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="6ca3787zz7n149b2d286qs777dd8357b" value="1" />                   </form>
                    </li>
```

Comment: I just mean, the name of that specific input, yes.

Comment: I don't own the website, so i cannot modify anything.

Comment: Is it always the last input in the form?

Comment: yes it is, but that doesn't return anything, when i tried javascript:alert(document.getElementsByName("return")[0].nextSibling) i just got "[object text]".

Comment: yeah, it works, thanks, but acdc solved it first.

Comment: @rid Never mind then, trolls going around randomly thumbing down perfectly legitimate questions.

Comment: @user2536979 are you aware there is a major difference between the nextSibling solution and the accepted answer?

Comment: @MrCode No, but what is the difference? I tried his second attempt that worked, i don't know why he deleted it.

Comment: The nextSibling solution gets the `return` input and then gets the next input. The accepted answer just gets the 5th input, whatever that may be. That seems to contradict statements in your question though. "the only thing that is 100% the same that i guess could be somehow used to retrieve the form name is:L2ZvcnVtcy8"

Comment: How is that contradictory? I just said that since it's always the same, it could somehow get the position of that, add 1 and get the other name which is what i originally intended.

Comment: That's what I'm referring to, the question reads as how to get the next input after the `return`, yet all the accepted answer does is gets the 5th input. If that's what you wanted then great, but why not just ask how to get the 5th input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check all the solutions below **in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/6sFwL/3/)**.

Some possibilities:

- Assuming there is only one element with the `name` `login` and that element is the `<form>`, you can use:

  ```
  document.getElementsByName('login')[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[4].name
  ```
- If the `return` `<input>` has a fixed `name` attribute, then this should work (the additional `.nextSibling` is because there is a text node between them):

  ```
  document.getElementsByName('return')[0].nextSibling.nextSibling.name
  ```
- If any other of of those `<input>`s has a fixed name, you can use (in the example I take the `<input>` with `name=task`):

  ```
  document.getElementsByName('task')[0].parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')[4].name);
  ```
- If all you **really** have is that fixed value, you'll have to use a `for` loop through all the `<input>`s:

  ```
  var lastResortName = (function () { for(var i=0, ipts = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), n = ipts.length; i < n; i++) { if (ipts[i].value === "L2ZvcnVtcy8=") return ipts[i+1].name; } })();
  ```

Note: If there are duplicated values for the mentioned `name` attributes, test with the index (`[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]` and so on) until you find the expected elements.

Answer (score -1):

That's really easy if you use JQuery:

```
$('input[type="hidden"]:eq(3)').attr('name')
```

Here your code running:
http://jsfiddle.net/7CHYa/

Comment: OP specified in his question he is adding JS directly in the browser, and such cannot make use of jquery..